# Pointer not assignable in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to create an array of strings, so I first use:

```
char** p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);  // count is the number of strings
```

But then trouble comes when I want to initialize those strings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    char* s = malloc(size_of_each_string);
    *p + i = s;  // THIS STEP INDUCES ERROR

    while (*s++ = *input++);  // initialize by copy
}
```

So I'm really confused. *p+i seems to be pointer arithmetic which shifts to another pointer. Pointer assignment in general is allowed (point to the same object). So why does such assignment not allowed? And how could I get around this to accomplish this task?

The error message is: Expression is not assignable.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `*(p+i)=s` instead of `*p+i=s`.

The things you're trying to do is to keep s in `(p+i)` address. For this you need to use `*(p+i)` instead of `*p+i`.

**About Error Message:**

Here the arithmetic expression *p+i will derive a value. But you can save a value only into a memory address. For this you're getting that error message.

Answer (score 4):

```
*p + i = s;
```

is equivalent to

```
*(p) + i = s;
```

due to [operator precedence.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) It yields an rvalue, which is not assignable.

Use parantheses instead:

```
*(p + i) = s;
```

or, even better, subscripting:

```
p[i] = s;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The expression `*p + i` is parsed as `(*p) + i` not as `*(p + i)`, so you need to do it explicitly. Or use normal array indexing syntax `p[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simplify your code by :

```
char** p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);  // count is the number of strings

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    p[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * size_of_each_string));
    strcpy(p[i], input);
}
```

Comment: Better to use a non-std `strlcpy()`